# Conjugacy Classes and Character Degrees of E8(2)

Tags: group-theory

The complex character table of the finite simple Chevalley group E8(2) is not known.
But we can deal with this group by considering the group as group of fixed points under a Frobenius morphism inside a connected reductive algebraic group G. Each element g in G has a Jordan decomposition g=su=us with s semisimple and u unipotent. My question (How we could use **Magma** in order to consider this group as as group of fixed points under a Frobenius morphism inside a connected reductive algebraic group G) . Or what is the best way to deal with E8(2) by using **Magma** for example finding the conjugacy classes of involutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the information you want [here](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Frank.Luebeck/chev/E82.html?LANG=de).

The group is too big to allow any direct computations in Magma or GAP.